# Error when Debugging Napa Excel Content Sample App

Tags: office365

I have just started playing around with the Office 365 Napa development tools and was working on the tutorial for building an Excel Content App - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220065.aspx.  The problem is that when I run the project it gives me an "app error" when the excel page is displayed.  Now, I looked to see if all the files loaded and it seems that the office.js file is not found on the appsformicrosoft.com site.  That seemed odd to me since I know others are developing apps this way and if the site was down there would be a firestorm.  For now I am going to assume something is not setup correctly for me.  So I am looking to see if anyone else has run into this issue and been able to resolve it.  Any help is appreciated.

Wade

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the issue is only happen when you debug your app in Napa, and at the same time you are signed in to MSDN sites.

If you logout from the MSDN, the issue is solved.

Comment: I actually needed to reinstall the Office 365 Napa Development tools.  Thanks for the answer regardless!